# Type conversion to a pointer of Float

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a linked list which could store different types of variables in **C**.
When I want to create a floating number pointer with the code below:

```c
int *dval = (int*)30;
float *fvalue = (float*)4.55;
```

compiler shows the error,

```sh
error: cannot convert to a pointer type  
float *fvalue = (float*)4.55;  
^~~~~
```

My question is why the first statement with type casting to **integer** pointer is right, but the second one to **floating** number pointer is wrong?
And how do I create a floating number pointer?

Comment: What memory address is 4.55 supposed to be?

Comment: You don't provide enough code to say for sure, but I suspect you should be using a union instead and this is a XY problem.

Comment: Why are you creating pointers but then assigning numerical values to them?  Why not `int dval = 30;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you think. The first line

```
int *dval = (int*)30;
```

is treating '30' as a memory address. The result is that 'dval' points to whatever is stored at that address.

The second line

```
float *fvalue = (float*)4.55;
```

is trying to do the same thing but '4.55' is not a valid memory address.

If you want to store actual values in your pointers you need to do something like

```
float float_val = 4.55;
float *fp = &float_val;
```